# How do I pass an arbitrary command line argument to a native Windows program from a MinGW shell?

Tags: windows, shell, mingw, msys

How do I pass an arbitrary command line argument to a native Windows program from a MinGW shell?

I would like a general solution, but a solution that works for any valid Windows filename would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shell is Bash. Cygwin/MSYS2 Bash can accept Windows paths, but you need to
deal with spaces and backslashes. Regarding backslashes:

```
program 'C:\alfa.txt'
program C:\\alfa.txt
program C:/alfa.txt
```

Regarding spaces:

```
program 'C:\alfa bravo.txt'
program C:\\alfa\ bravo.txt
program C:/alfa\ bravo.txt
```

As you can see, if you are supplying Windows paths, this is pretty straight
forward. The only issue you might get is if you are trying to supply Bash paths
to a Windows native program:

```
program /tmp/alfa.txt
```

Windows native programs have no concept of `/tmp` or even `/`. Cygwin/MSYS2 have
`cygpath` to assist in converting these paths:

```
program $(cygpath -m /tmp/alfa.txt)
program "$(cygpath -w /tmp/alfa.txt)"
program "$(cygpath -m '/tmp/alfa bravo.txt')"
program "$(cygpath -m /tmp/alfa\ bravo.txt)"
program "$(cygpath -w '/tmp/alfa bravo.txt')"
program "$(cygpath -w /tmp/alfa\ bravo.txt)"
```

Side note: MinGW is an old project. You should be using Cygwin or MSYS2.

Comment: What if the path I want to pass has spaces in it?